# Python f string curly braces

Tags: python, f-string

new to python and programming in general.
Forr the following code, why would 'a''b''c''d' be printed separately for each loop, I understand that 'abcd' would be treated as an array but does putting it in curly braces have a special meaning? Is this a function unique to python?

```
for i in range(4):
    print(f"{'abcd'[i]}")
```

Was just wondering about how exactly f strings and the curly braces work.

Comment: nothing to do with `f` strings, you're indexing that array with `[i]`, `i` is the index and at any given iteration it's one of `0, 1, 2, 3`

Comment: your code is same if you do `print('abcd'[i])`

Answer (score 1):

> Was just wondering about how exactly f strings and the curly braces
> work.

This is described by Abstract of [PEP 498 – Literal String Interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) following way

> (...)F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals,
> using a minimal syntax. It should be noted that an f-string is really
> an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value. In Python
> source code, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with ‘f’, which
> contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with
> their values.(...)

> Is this a function unique to python?

No. Recent versions of JavaScript have similar feature named [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which are enclosed in backtick characters, for example

```
let letters = "abcd";
for(i=0;i<letters.length;i+=1){
    console.log(`Letter ${letters[i]}`)
}
```

make console output

```
Letter a
Letter b
Letter c
Letter d
```